# How do I solve the error Public key for jenkins-2.238-1.1.noarch.rpm is not installed when I run yum update for jenkins installation for the AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, yum

Getting the error attached when I yum update my aws ec2

Downloading packages:
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/2/jenkins/packages/jenkins-2.238-1.1.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID 45f2c3d5: NOKEY

Public key for jenkins-2.238-1.1.noarch.rpm is not installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try installing its key manually:

```
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.io.key
```

or

```
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
```

as shown in official jenkins [website](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#red-hat-centos).

Comment: Correct key is now: https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.io-2023.key or https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins is now doing key rotation.

Reference: https://get.jenkins.io/redhat/

The key you now need:

sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.io-2023.key

Comment: I ran into this with dnf and Rocky Linux.  I think previously I had installed jenkins manually from an rpm because I needed to grab a newer one than available.  This resolved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

### Debian/Ubuntu

`wget -qO - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | apt-key add -`

### Red Hat/CentOS

`rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key`

Blog post https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/07/27/repository-signing-keys-changing/